# How to add a 32-bit input in Quartus 2

Tags: schematics, input, quartus-ii

Can you help me to add a multiple pins input in Quartus 2? If there is not a default one, how can I add it by MegaWizard Plug-in Manager? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are meaning in the Quartus Schematic?

If so, just change the name of the `input` (or `output` or `bidir`) to `whatever[31..0]`. The array indices are the same as if you did it in Verilog, except that a `..` is used instead of a `:`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I saw it ... Sorry that I'm a beginner :) ...